# Vue Mixin for using with child components

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

I've built a multi-layered dropdown component, called `<my-dropdown>` that accepts at minimum `props: ['options']`. Options can be a 1-D array, or an array of objects, each with their own `options` array. I'm keeping track of the selected option with an array of indexes (e.x. "Down" would be `[1,3]`).

```
const ddOptions = [
    "All",
    {
        "name": "Turtles",
        "options": ["All", "The", "Way", "Down"]
    }
]
```

I'm trying to decide how to deal with setting the label of the dropdown (current selection) and using the current selection in the parent. My current solution is to use a mixin called `dropdownParentMixin` that's used anywhere a dropdown is used, that takes the emitted index path from the parent, and computes the label, and anything else about the selected option, and feeds the label back into the dropdown.

Dropdown:

```
<template>
    <span>{{label}}</span>
    <my-menu 
        :options="options"
        @choose="setChoice"
    ></my-menu>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        props:["label", "options"],
        methods: {
            setChoice: function(index_path){
                this.$emit('change',index_path)
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Parent:

```
<template>
    <my-dropdown
        :options="ddOptions"
        :label="label"
        @change="handleChange"
    ></my-dropdown>
</template>
<script>
    module.exports = {
        mixins: [dropdownParentMixin],
        methods: {
            handleChange: function(index_path){
                // defined in mixin
                this.setPath(index_path)
            },
            doSomething: function(){
                // use this.path
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Mixin

```
const dropdownParentMixin = {
    methods: {
        setPath: function(path){
            this.path = path
        },
        getElement: function() {
            // drill down to the correct element in ddOptions
            this.label == ddOptions[...].label
            this.someAttribute = ddOptions[...].attribute
        }
    },
    /*computed: {
        label: function(){
            // some magic based on this.path
            return computedLabel
        }
    }*/
}
```

My question is: **Is it bad practice to require a Mixin to use a component?** If so, what other ways are there to solve the problem?

Comment: Yeah, it is bad practice. Why not just have the computed `label` within the dropdown component itself?

Comment: I could compute the `label` from within the dropdown. The problem is that the labels aren't necessarily unique, so it's the `index_path` that identifies the selected option. I guess one way could be to update the data model so that each option has a unique identifier.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The dropdown component only has one `label` prop and since you know the `index_path` in the `setChoice` method, what info are you missing in that context?

Comment: Ah, I see. The `label` is unique from the dropdown's point of view and can easily be computed from within the dropdown.
The problem is I want to use `this.path` and get the element's attributes from within the Parent
This will duplicate a lot of code, since the iteration in the `getElement()` method (formerly `label()` computation) is similar to that in `doSomething()`

Comment: That's all pretty vague and I'm still not seeing why those functions can't exist in the dropdown component. If the parent needs access to the returned values, they can be passed up with events

Comment: Thanks. Yeah in clarifying the question, I answered it myself. I think I'll have the dropdown do the computations and emit the object back to the parent as an event.